# How to solve or get Get approximate solution of this type of differential equation $A\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+B\frac{dy}{dx}+Cy+Dy^3=f(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$A\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+B\frac{dy}{dx}+Cy+Dy^3=f(x)$$

A,B,C,D are all constants,and $B^2-4AC<0$,when $D=0$,it is the model of damped harmonic oscillator,and I know how to solve it.But when $D$ appears,I don't know how to get the exact solution or use some method to approximate the solution. So can someone please guide me on this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not a numerical integration ? (After all you need it for many $f$).

Comment: Do you know what $f(x)$ is?